# runTest does not run on main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing, androidx-test

I am writing a test and I get this error from a standard library:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
```

This is my simplified test method:

```
@Test
fun useAppContext() = runTest {
    assert(isMainThread())
}
```

How can I make this test succeed? I need to add an observer somewhere in my test which fails because I need to do so on the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like `runBlocking` (and like code written directly in `@Test` methods), code within `runTest` is run on the test thread by default, rather than on the main thread.  This is *usually* the behavior you want, because if you don't yield the main thread, it will not run layouts, and your UI will be completely frozen.

##### To run a specific part of your test on the UI thread

If you just have a specific part of your test that should be run on the UI thread, such as your example of the `addObserver` call, you can switch the coroutine dispatcher for that specific part of the test.

Surround the relevant part of your method with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`

```kotlin
@Test
fun someTestMethod() = runTest {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        assert(isMainThread())
    }
}
```

##### To run your entire test on the UI thread

If you *do* want to run your test on the main thread (for example, because it's a simple test that doesn't involve any layouts, or because you want to manually control when you yield the main thread with `suspend` methods (such as Compose's `withFrameNanos`), this can be done with the [`@UiThreadTest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/annotation/UiThreadTest) annotation.

Annotate the test method (or the class, if all `@Test`, `@Before`, and `@After` methods should be run on the UI thread) with `@UiThreadTest`.

```kotlin
@Test
@UiThreadTest
fun someTestMethod() = runTest {
    assert(isMainThread())
}
```